# How to reset fetch call if the length of value is 0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello i have fetch on an input. When the user types his content, the fetch and throttle functions will be executed. The fetch call will be executed no matter what the length of the input is. So I have to update the fetch call when the length of the value is zero, because the fetch call is no needed when the length of the value is zero. Can anyone help me with that?

```
const throttling = useCallback(
    throttle(function(value) {
      const myFetch = fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/auto-suggest?input=' + encodeURIComponent(value))
      if (value.length > 0) {
        myFetch.then(response => response.json()).then(setSearchResult)
      } else {
        console.log('is 0')
      }
    }, 500),
    []
  )

function handleChange(event) {
    throttling(event.target.value)
    onChange(event.target.value)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you check for value length before you even start executing the the fetch function in the first place. Or you can check if the content is empty before you start your fetch execution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can put `fetch` inside of your `if` statement. Try as the following:

```
if (value.length > 0) {
     const myFetch = fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/auto-suggest?input=' + encodeURIComponent(value));
     myFetch.then(response => response.json()).then(setSearchResult);
} else {
     console.log('is 0');
}
```

In this way the `fetch` will be executed only if `value.length > 0` becomes `true`.

Comment: No that doesn't work, because it stays with the latest fetch call. I think the fetch has to update when the `length` of the `value` is zero. But don't know how